# multi login pages/scenarios

Tags: keycloak

we are planning to use keycloack as identityserver for our company. I read their documentation and could not find any thing related to multi login page for the same scenarios. Is it possible to achive this without changing keycloak code and just use custom thing based on the what they provide to us. One way is using multiple realms which each of them has own login page but for our requirments we could not use multiple realm. I need one realm which has multiple login scenarios and based on the query param keyloack shows the different login page to the user which each of this login page has own auth flow. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_theme_selector

> By default the theme configured for the realm is used, with the exception of clients being able to override the login theme. This behavior can be changed through the Theme Selector SPI.
>
> This could be used to select different themes for desktop and mobile devices by looking at the user agent header, for example.
>
> To create a custom theme selector you need to implement ThemeSelectorProviderFactory and ThemeSelectorProvider.

You need to code it. Fortunately, there is SPI for that, so you don't need to fork Keycloak code. Just implemement Theme Selector SPI and deployment for your custom code.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I will try with this way.